# cannot convert to egg file for panda3d

Tags: python, panda3d

I am a beginner in panda3d, recently i came across blender 2.77 for modelling. I was disapointed to find that it cannot export egg files supported by panda3d, i searched online and found yabee and chicken but after installing those addons to blender also, i did'nt find an egg file exporter in the exporter's list.

I tried using obj and dae files in blender and then converting them to egg through obj2egg(did not load mtl files) and dae2egg(i cannot see any other color than white in pview).
I have no idea of where i am wrong.

I am sure i have done the conversion correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to add some paragraph breaks to this; it's hard to read.

Comment: atleast can anyone suggest me another 3d engine???

Comment: That would be [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also, consider asking in [gamedev.se].

Comment: Have you check the checkbox of Panda3d EGG format? When I check it, the export menu appear Panda3D(.egg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also new at Panda3D and I solved a problem similar to yours just a few hours ago.

There are two ways to solve your Problem:

1. Download another version of Blender. The last version working with YABEE is 2.66.
2. Just export your model as a `.x` file (DirectX native) this works great with Panda3D

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I had left hope. Thanx for your help, i'll try it soon

Comment: I did try to export my model as a .x but found all the colours in the model missing. It was plain white with little shading.

Answer (score 2):

Common error when using YABEE: Not only do you need to copy it into the addons directory, you also need to activate it in Blender.

Comment: Maybe add a bit of info on how you "activate it"?